# Problema al asignar un limite al bucle for en C

Tags: c, bucle-for, while

Tengo un problema y es que quiero crear una calculadora, pero NO una que me pida la cantidad de números a sumar y luego todos los números, quiero hacer una mas cercana a las que vemos por ejemplo en google, una calculadora que al poner 5+5+5 en la misma linea de un scanf y presionar enter, de como resultado 15.

Se que por ejemplo puedo utilizar un `while(scanf("%d",&numeros[i])=='\n')` introduce números en el buffer hasta que le presione espacio, el problema es que no se como seguir después, como asignar todos esos números a algún array y como contar la cantidad de dígitos que tengo para poder establecer un limite al bucle for.

Comment: Te invito a leer: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Edita la pregunta y trata de especificar de forma **CLARA** el problema, de lo contrario, la pregunta terminará cerrada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El siguiente código realiza la suma con una sola entrada de datos, puedes ingresar enteros o flotantes, la secuencia de ingreso es de la siguiente manera: numero seguido del signo mas y seguido de otro numero y otro signo mas, etc. tal que así 4+2+1+50 ... sin espacios hasta presionar la tecla Enter, no tiene un validador, por lo que debes procurar ingresar caracteres validos y en el orden correcto. Hay muchos videos de este tipo en youtube solo que están en ingles, seguro que encuentras mas ejemplos para documentarte todavía mas, si lo que buscas es hacer una calculadora un tanto mas funcional.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TAM 25 //longitud del array 'entrada' de tipo char

//puntero global de tipo char, para referenciar caracter a caracter los elementos del array 'entrada'
char *ptr;

//convierte segmentos del array 'entrada' a valores tipo float
float parseFactor(void){
    char copia[TAM];
    int i = 0;

    strcpy(copia,ptr);

    while(copia[i] != '+' && i < TAM) i++;
    copia[i] = '\0';

    ptr += i;

    return atof(copia);
}

//realiza sumas y retorna el resultado
float parseSuma(void){
    float valor2, valor1 = parseFactor();

    while(*ptr == '+'){
        ptr++;
        valor2 = parseFactor();
        valor1 += valor2;
    }

    return valor1;
}

int main(void){
    char entrada[TAM];

    printf("Ingrese operacion: ");
    scanf("%s",entrada);

    ptr = entrada;

    printf("resultado: %g",parseSuma());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona exactamente como quería, el único problema es que no termino de entender el código pero ya le voy a buscar la vuelta¿Tenes por casualidad alguno de esos vídeos que mencionaste?

Comment: claro, es este: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N55XNj8KjC4 me base en este video para formular la respuesta, notaras que el código lo modifique para que acepte flotantes ademas de enteros y para que pueda calcular números que tengan mas de un solo dígito.

Comment: Se agradece su respuesta, sin embargo, stackoverflow no es una comunidad que hace tareas o que realice códigos enteros, aquí simplemente se resuelve dudas especificas orientado a un determinado problema (en este caso la pregunta del OP no está formulada correctamente).

Comment: Si... De igual manera no era una tarea así que quédate tranquilo, no hice ningún tipo de trampa, simplemente soy yo tratando de entender todo lo que puedo y me plantee ese reto, el tipo respondió perfectamente y me introdujo a ese termino de "parse" que voy a proceder a revisar mucho.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes tener 2 variables simplemente de modo que una sea donde almacenas el valor del scanf y la otra donde se almacena la suma de datos

```
while(scanf("%i ", &num) ! = '\n') suma+=num;

printf("%i", sum) ;
```

Comment: Probé ejecutar el programa así, si bien me almacena tantos valores como yo quiero, no se detiene en ningún momento, yo vi que hay una manera de detenerlo cuando yo presione espacio que es 
while(scanf("%i ", &num) == '\n') pero aun así cuando uso tu solución el printf me escribe 0

Comment: @Leandro En la documentación de la función [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) en ningún momento dice que puede retornar un salto de línea: `\n`. Te recomiendo formular bien la pregunta para que puedas recibir una mejor ayuda por parte de la comunidad. ¡Saludos!